# Are baby gem dense enough for low hedges?

Tags: leaves, shrubs, hedge, branches, boxwood

I would like to have a very low hedge: about a foot tall. Are baby gem boxwoods dense enough for that? In other words, will there be enough leaves to cover the branches at the bottom and to look dense? And do they have branches that road down to form a skirt?

Comment: Are you planning to use it like for example in some gardens where flower or vegetable beds are “framed”? So will you be looking *down*, or will you really look at the sides and the soil level, e.g. by planting the boxwood on a raised bed or similar?

Comment: and...what part of the world are you in?  Boxwood is often sold at the big box stores in areas where it is not truly hardy

Comment: I am in Philadelphia. And yes, looking down so looking for a framing effect